# disable dolly in CameraControls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-drei

I have a Jupiter component, which represents Jupiter 3d model. I can't find a property or soluton to disable zoom when user scrolls

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useGLTF, CameraControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
const { DEG2RAD } = THREE.MathUtils;
export function Jupiter({ onClick, name, isChoosed }) {
  const group = useRef();
  const { camera } = useThree();
  const cameraControlsRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isChoosed) {
      cameraControlsRef?.current?.zoom(-camera.zoom / 1.5, true);
      cameraControlsRef?.current?.rotate(-180 * DEG2RAD, 0, true);
    } else {
      cameraControlsRef?.current?.zoom(camera.zoom / 0.5, true);
      cameraControlsRef?.current?.rotate(180 * DEG2RAD, 0, true);
    }
  }, [isChoosed]);
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/jupiter.gltf");
  useFrame(() => {
    group.current.rotation.y += 0.0008;
  });
  return (
    <group
      ref={group}
      dispose={null}
      onClick={(event) => onClick(event, name, camera, cameraControlsRef)}
    >
      <CameraControls ref={cameraControlsRef} />
      <group rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
        <group rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.1}>
          <group rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={100}>
            <mesh
              geometry={nodes.Sphere_Material_0.geometry}
              material={materials.Material}
              scale={0.0018}
            />
          </group>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/jupiter.gltf");
```

I tried to set dollySpeed to zero, but with this property scroll in the area of planet disables completely
Then I tried to set property mouseButtons, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<CameraControls ref={cameraControlsRef} enableZoom={false} />
```

Comment: doesn't work :( 
As I remember, this property is used in OrbitControls, not CameraControls

Comment: Try: <CameraControls minZoom={0.01} maxZoom={0.01} />